# how to call react useEffect again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My component uses a hook which uses another hook which in turn uses another hook(let's call this `hook1`).

The `hook1` looks like this:

```
function useANTBalance(guardianId) {
  const antTokenContract = useANTTokenContract();
  const error = null
  const [data, setData] = useState({ antbalance: { amount : bigNum(0) }});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const amount = await antTokenContract.balanceOf(guardianId)
      setData({ antbalance: { amount : bigNum(amount) }} )
    }
    getData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
  
  return { data, error }
}
```

Every 10 seconds in an interval, my component rerenders, meaning that the hook it's using gets called again, which in turn calls `hook1` again. So `hook1` gets called every 10 seconds.

In use `useEffect` above, I am making async call to get the balance. The problem is that even if `balanceOf` above returns different amount, `useEffect` doesn't get called, because I have `[]` as dependency which doesn't change.

if i remove the dependency `[]` , then `useEffect` gets called so many times, like it gets recursive and my page gets unresponsive.

Any ideas what I can do ? Not a react dev unfortunatelly.

Comment: A hook without a provided dependency array is called every time the component re-renders. As your hook modifies the state, causing a re-render, this leads to an infinite loop. You should either select a dependency (perhaps one updated by the other hook?) which relyable triggers the hook or refactor `getData` to a function outside a hook and call it from a `setInterval` callback, which you are probably already doing in the other part of your application.

Comment: The other hook that calls `hook1` doesn't depend any variable, so it's impossible at this stage to make sure that the other hook gives some dependency to `hook1`.  as for the refactor for `getData`, I put it in the `useEffect` so that I can do async call in there. Not sure how taking it outside would help

Comment: `useEffect` hooks are used to perform actions once a component re-renders OR a certain property changes - which also causes a re-render. As your function is causing a re-render itself and does not depend on any other property, a `useEffect` hook is not the right place to call it in. You want to call the function every 10 seconds, so I would suggest defining it outside of a hook and calling it from a `setInterval` callback as opposed to a hook.

Comment: can't do setInterval, because I am using `urql` which has `useQuery` which calls some queries every 10 seconds(I pass 10 second option). So, doing `setInterval` can't be an option.